# MS Word VBA to link previous footer for multiple sections and pages

Tags: vba, ms-word, footer

I have a MS Word (2010) and my document has hundreds of sections when I really only need a limited number of sections with the same footer.

I'd like a macro that can cycle through the selected pages and change all the footers to Link to Previous.

I recorded a macro which will do it for one section, how do I alter the code so if I selected a bunch of pages (e.g. 25) it will zip through all of them?

```
Sub LinkToPrev_Foot()
'
' LinkToPrev_Foot Macro
'
'
    Selection.HeaderFooter.LinkToPrevious = Not Selection.HeaderFooter. _
        LinkToPrevious
   ' ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.NextHeaderFooter
End Sub
```

Comment: Why so many Sections?

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop through the sections of the document. The code below assumes you are only using one of the three types of footer.

```
Public Sub LinkToPrev_Foot()
    Dim ftr As HeaderFooter
    Dim sec As Section

    For Each sec In ActiveDocument.Sections
        'can't link the first section to a previous one
        If sec.Index > 1 Then
            'if document has other types of footer you'll need to loop through them
            sec.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = True
        End If
    Next sec
End Sub
```

Comment: I do not want to loop through all sections of the document.  I only want to loop through the sections of the selected pages.  So if I have 50 sections in my document of 100 pages and if I only have pages 10-35 selected I only want to loop through those few sections.

Comment: @user918967 - then simply change `ActiveDocument.Sections` to `Selection.Sections`

Comment: Do you know why some of the `Section.Footers` fail to `LinkToPrevious = True`? 
I also tested it by adding a line inside the loop 
`Debug.Print "----------------- " & sec.Index & sec.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious` 
The Print also shows some `LinkToPrevious` return `False`. 
eg: 
`----------------- 235True
----------------- 236True
----------------- 237False
----------------- 238True
----------------- 239True`

Comment: @Nor.Z - if your document contains more than two hundred sections you are highly likely not using section breaks correctly. Section breaks are only required when there is a change in page layout. I would not be surprised if a document with that many sections has become corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

#### another raised issue

[the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68103559/9549068) already gave a good solution.

However, it doesnt quite work in my case -- **some of the `Section.Footers` fail to `LinkToPrevious = True`**.

I dont know why.

#### solution (workaround)

Then I tried to **reset** the `Footer` for each `Section` to see if it can solve the issue. And it did.

```vb
Sub aa_test_main()
  ' >>
  Dim sec As Section
  For Each sec In Selection.Sections ' ActiveDocument.Sections
    ' ( `If sec.Index > 1` is not needed, cuz: 
    ' ( its only for the First page in the document, 
    ' ( when you are using Selection, its unlikely you would select the First page (slight performance boost)
    With sec.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
      ' @key:
      ' You must delete the Footer, then add it back (for resetting it). 
      ' Otherwise, the `LinkToPrevious = True` may not work for some Sections.
      ' (idk why)
      ' @atten: This will delete the format of your Footer!!! & only add back a PageNum. 
      .Range.Delete 
      .PageNumbers.Add
      .LinkToPrevious = True ' @main
    End With
    ' Debug.Print "--- " & sec.Index & sec.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious
  Next
End Sub
```

- ***Attention:*** `.Range.Delete` This will ***delete*** the format of your Footer!!! & `.PageNumbers.Add` only add back a PageNum.

  You may ***NOT want*** this behavior.
- (this is only a workaround, waiting for a better solution.)

Comment: `.Range.Delete` isn't an issue as linking a section's header or footer to the previous one will delete it anyway. Adding a page number to the header or footer is also nonsensical as it will also be deleted with `.LinkToPrevious = True`